# Passing params for creating and updating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I wonder, is there an easier way to do the following

```
#controller's action
@my_model = MyModel.create field1: params[:field1],
               field2: params[:field2],
               field3: params[:field3],
               field4: params[:field4]
               # and so on.....
```

I would use

```
  @my_model = MyModel.create params
```

but would it work since `params` **always** contains other keys added by Rails?

P.S.
The same question for updating a model (would this work properly?)

```
MyModel.update_attributes params
```

Comment: If it's coming from a form you should be able to pass in `params[:my_model]` or whatever it's sending. If you can't, that means that you're not using the Rails form/form fields, or aren't naming them properly. Either that, or you should use a form model containing only the fields you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send params as a nested hash like

```
{:my_model => {:field1 => 'blah', :field2 => 'blah'}, :controller => 'something', :action => 'something_else'}
```

This way you could just say

```
@my_model = MyModel.create params[:my_model]
```

Rails does this automatically if you have followed the conventions while creating the form.

Comment: In this case, use form helpers `(form_for)`

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts This will be helpful.

Comment: if I can't use form_for, is there any way to simply my code, for example, by using reflection or something like that?

Comment: If you can't use form_for,  that shouldn't prevent you from still adhering to rails conventions,  i.e if you use text_field_tag,  you can still arrange for the input element name to be 'my_model[field1]'